# Does the North know that Ramsay did not marry Arya?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Roose Bolton arranged the marriage between his son Ramsay and the daughter of the former Lord Paramount of the North, Eddard Stark. But the Arya his son married is an imposter. Does he and the rest of the North know this?

This marriage is very important for him, because it solidifies his claim to the lordship. So outing his daughter-in-law wouldn't be very wise. He would also anger the Lannisters because he arranged the marriage with them. The outing would mean, that the Lannisters tried to cheat the North, it would also mean that they had to admit that they don't have any more hostages of the North.

But isn't there any lord in the North that would recognize the imposter, which is Sansa's childhood friend Jeyne, IIRC?

There should have been festivities that Arya took part in, so the lords should know her.

Comment: Are you asking about plot developments in future books?  The latest development I remember is that Jeyne was rescued and delivered to Stannis's snowbound camp.  Only future books will tell what (if anything) will come of that.

Comment: @GEdgar no, I'm asking, whether the people living in the North know, that jeyne is not who she pretends to be.

Comment: AFAIR, re the books - where the imposter was impersonating Arya, it was felt that Arya had been missing long enough that people were expected to be unsure what she looked like now. Theon's testimony as to her identity as Arya pretty much sealed it in their eyes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some of them may have some suspicions, but they don't seem to really know. As pointed out in the comments, Theon is supposed to know Arya, so Bolton uses him as a witness to confirm Jeyne as Arya:

> Theon Greyjoy had grown up with Arya Stark. Theon would have known an imposter. If he was seen to accept Bolton's feigned girl as Arya, the northern lords who had gathered to witness the match would have no grounds to question her legitimacy. Stout and Slate, Whoresbane Umber, the quarrelsome Ryswells, Hornwood mens and Cerwyn cousins, fat Lord Wyman Manderly... Not one of them had known Ned Stark's daughters half so well as he. And if a few entertained private doubts, surely they would be wise enough to keep those misgivings to themselves.
>
> *They are using me to cloak their deception, putting mine own face on their lie.* That was why Roose Bolton had clothed him as a lord again, to play his part on this mummer's farce.
>
> (A Dance with Dragons, *The Prince of Winterfell*, pages 533-534, Bantam Books Mass Market International Edition)

Lady Barbrey might know about it, as she is one of the only one to truly support Bolton. But even her case is unclear. And Wyman Manderly seems to believe Jeyne is the real Arya, as the wedding is one of the reasons why he wants Davos to look for Rickon:

> "Roose Bolton has Lord Eddard's daughter. To thwart him White Harbor must have Ned's son... and the direwolf."
>
> (A Dance with Dragons, *Davos*, page 433, Bantam Books Mass Market International Edition)

Also remember that Jon sent Mance to get her because he thought it was Arya, and even when receiving Ramsay's letter he still thinks it's her. I think the northern lords who join Stannis also mention saving Arya as part of their motivations, though I can't find a reference for that right now.

Comment: It should be noted that that quote from Wyman Manderly was made before he had set eyes on Ramsay's bride, at the time he was just repeating what he had heard. So it still possible that, like the other lords, he may harbour secret doubts about her identity after seeing her at the wedding.

Comment: Good point (and nice pun ;) )